# Using aws.s3::get_bucket_df() returns errors when trying to retrieve bucket meta data?

Tags: r, dataframe, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a repository in S3:

```
my_bucket:
    folder1
      subfolder11
        subfolder111
    folder2
      subfolder21
       subfolder221
```

I am trying to connect and load all files in all relevant folders in my bucket. Here is how I am trying to do this:

```
library(aws.s3)
bl <- bucketlist()

### Builds a dataframe of the files in a bucket###
dfBucket <- get_bucket_df(bucket = "my_bucket", prefix = "folder1/", max = Inf)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error in z[["Owner"]][["ID"]] : subscript out of bounds

Please advise.

UPDATE:
I actually can run this command on other buckets and the issue is focusing on very long file names stored in this particular bucket in S3.

Please advise how to solve it given the new info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by using `rbindlist(dfBucket)`.

In my case `get_bucket()` did work and returned a list of bucket contents.

`get_bucket_df()` returned an error:

> Error in z[["Owner"]][["ID"]] : subscript out of bounds

I have tried to find out what can solve my issue and used `rbindlist` which solved my issue.

Those who commented and criticized my answer, I am totally don't agree. If you know how to solve, please share your answer. It's not professional to throw critics without providing a solution!

Comment: Sure, will do. Please look at the updated answer shortly

Comment: how did you use rbindlist, could you give an example of the full code?

Comment: @AlexOrtner I just applied it on it.

Comment: It worked for me but not for the dataframe syntax as I would understand above answer.
The code working is:
`my_file_names=rbindlist(get_bucket(bucket = Bucket,prefix=Prefix))$Key`
not working and still failing with error is
`rbindlist(get_bucket_df(bucket = Bucket,prefix=Prefix))$Key`

Comment: You should probably note that `rbindlist` is from the `data.table` package

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came based on using "get_bucket" instead of "get_bucket_df":

```
 # 1. Use "get_bucket"
 df_bucket_data <- get_bucket(bucket_name, prefix = aws_s3_user_bucket_data)

 # 2. Init list of files in bucket folder
 list_bucket_data <- c()

 # 3. Add names of files in bucket folder
 for(i in 1:length(df_bucket_data)) {
    list_bucket_data <- c(
        list_bucket_data, 
        df_bucket_data[[i]]$Key)
 }

 # 4. Review result
 print(list_bucket_data)
```

The "get_bucket_df" works not stable and gives me sometimes an "Error in z[["Owner"]][["ID"]] : subscript out of bounds".

So, this solution fixed the problem.