# Spread dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, spread

I have the following `dataframe`/`tibble` sample:

```
structure(list(name = c("Contents.Key", "Contents.LastModified", 
"Contents.ETag", "Contents.Size", "Contents.Owner", "Contents.StorageClass", 
"Contents.Bucket", "Contents.Key", "Contents.LastModified", "Contents.ETag"
), value = c("2019/01/01/07/556662_cba3a4fc-cb8f-4150-859f-5f21a38373d0_0e94e664-4d5e-4646-b2b9-1937398cfaed_2019-01-01-07-54-46-064", 
"2019-01-01T07:54:47.000Z", "\"378d04496cb27d93e1c37e1511a79ec7\"", 
"24187", "e7c0d260939d15d18866126da3376642e2d4497f18ed762b608ed2307778bdf1", 
"STANDARD", "vfevvv-edrfvevevev-streamed-data", "2019/01/01/07/556662_cba3a4fc-cb8f-4150-859f-5f21a38373d0_33a8ba28-245c-490b-99b2-254507431d47_2019-01-01-07-54-56-755", 
"2019-01-01T07:54:57.000Z", "\"df8cc7082e0cc991aa24542e2576277b\""
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to spread the names column using `tidyr::spread()` function but I don't get the desired result

```
df %>% tidyr::spread(key = name, value = value)
```

I get an error:

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows:...

Also tried with `melt` function same result.

I have connected to S3 using `aws.s3::get_bucket()` function and trying to convert it to dataframe. I am aware there is a `aws.s3::get_bucket_df()` function which should do this but it doesn't work (you may look at my [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863009/r-load-json-files-from-s3).

After I've got the bucket list, I've unlisted it and run `enframe` command. 
Please advise.

Comment: What is the expected result? Column 2 looks a bit messy and might need cleaning.

Comment: @NelsonGon thanks for the answer, please advise why my solution didn't work with spreading right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a new column first(introduces `NA`s, will have to deal with them).

```
df %>% 
mutate(RN=row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(RN) %>% 
  spread(name,value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please explain why my solution didn't work? Why I couldn't just spread it?

Comment: It's because when you spread  straight away, you have for instance Content.Etag with similar values at 3,10. The way `spread` works is that you must have unique row values for the data to spread correctly.

Comment: And how do you suggest to deal with the NA's and collapse it? @nelsongon

Comment: Frankly, it depends on the aim. However, in this case using 0 seems appropriate. You can use the fill argument in `spread` like so: `spread(name,value,fill=0)`

Comment: Can you please have a look on the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863009/r-load-json-files-from-s3?noredirect=1&lq=1 related to this? Maybe you have a good solution @nelsongon

Comment: Not really familiar with `json`(currently) unfortunately. Hopefully someone looks at this question and follows to the linked question and hopefully helps.

Comment: It's not the JSON who makes the problem but connection to S3 and reading the bucket meta data. @nelsongon

Comment: Solved by rbindlist(dfBucket)!

Comment: Great then. You could place it as an answer on your question for future users.